# Bubble sort an array of chars

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, 2d

I am trying to do a bubble sort of a char 2d array without using any C library functions, this is the code i have but when i compile and run, nothing gets sorted.

Strings is declared: char Strings[25][1000]; and gets filled with input taken in by the scanner.

```
  char temp;

  for(int i =1; i < NUM; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < NUM; j++){
      if (Strings[i-1] > Strings[i]){
        temp = *Strings[i];
        *Strings[i] = *Strings[j];
        *Strings[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Anna Truelove, welcome to SO, did you google your error message?

Comment: `Strings[i-1]` : When `i` is 0, it becomes `Strings[-1]`, resulting in unauthorized access. Also type of `Strings[index]` isn't `char*`, if Its 2D Array. So `Strings[i] = Strings[j];` isn't possible.

Comment: Also `Strings[i-1]` and `Strings[i]` are next to each other, but `Strings[i]` and `Strings[j]` are not next to each other. and Use `strcmp` instead of `>` to compare strings.

Comment: sample [code](https://ideone.com/h2DdwP)

Comment: please update your code to show how `Strings` was declared.

Comment: The assignment operator cannot be used for char arrays in C, for historical reasons. You have to use a function that conceptually copies characters one by one, e.g. `strcpy` or `memcpy`.

Comment: @Anna If you don't want to use `strcpy` and `strcmp`, you have to implement them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot compare strings like you do in `C`. So, you can try `strcmp` function.

First, include string header file. i.e, `#include <string.h>`

```
char tmp[1000];
int i,j,flag;
for(i = 0, flag=1; i < NUM && flag==1; i++){
     for (j = 0, flag=0; j < NUM-i-1; j++){
        if (strcmp(Strings[j],Strings[j+1]) > 0){
                strcpy(tmp,Strings[j]);
                strcpy(Strings[j],Strings[j+1]);
                strcpy(Strings[j+1],tmp);
                flag=1;
         }
      }
}
for(i=0;i<NUM;i++){
        printf("%s\n",Strings[i]);
}
```

By using flag in Bubble sort, it improves its time complexity slightly.